# Why aren't my TextBoxes being counted?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, textbox, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I'm trying to change the `Text` in my `TextBoxes` in a form but I can't find out how to account for all of my `TextBoxes` without doing them individually...

I've tried the following code; however, my `int i` returns `0`.

```
int i = 0;

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox")
    {
        i++;
        ((TextBox)c).Text = CleanInput(((TextBox)c).Text);
    }
}
```

I'm just confused on how to grab all of my `TextBoxes` and check them...

Comment: Also if u need to search control inside controls, you need to add some recursion!

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to do! @Graffito had the right method below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all TextBoxes are not children of "this", use a recursive method:

```
CleanTextBoxes(this)

private void CleanTextBoxes(Control TheControl)
{ 
  foreach (Control c in TheControl.Controls)
  {
    if (c is TextBox) ((TextBox)c).Text = CleanInput(((TextBox)c).Text);
    else CleanTextBoxes(c) ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int i = 0;

foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if (c is TextBox)
    {
       i++;
       ((TextBox)c).Text = CleanInput(((TextBox)c).Text);
    }
}
```